# Need to add a hyperlinkfield to a gridview containing data from another column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a gridview that gets data from an sqldatasource and as a results gets 3 columns from an SQL query: ID, description and price.

What I want to do is adding another column with an hyperlink in the format of page.aspx?id=x where x is the ID code from the first column. This for each row in the table.

I've been looking all morning for how to do this, all I got is that I have to manage the RowDataBound event and use an hyperlinkfield but couldn't find anything else that explained how they actually work together, even the msdn article is kind of vague on the subject or just doesn't have any relevant help for my specific case as I'm managing the gridview from the code-behind.
Also haven't been able to figure how to access strings from the other columns, since it's what I need to insert in the resulting hyperlink.

Here's what I got so far for the creation of the gridview:

```
private void FillGrid(string qid)
{
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = Connessione.connectionString;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT art_tessuto_articolo, art_tessuto_descrizione, lipre_prezzo FROM lipre INNER JOIN listini_tessuti ON lipre.lipre_codice = listini_tessuti.listini_codice INNER JOIN art_tessuti ON lipre.lipre_articolo = art_tessuti.art_tessuto_articolo WHERE lipre_codice = @qid AND lipre_prezzo <> 0";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("qid", qid);

    GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
    GridView1.PageSize = 500;
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;

    GridView1.DataBind();


}
```

Comment: This video will help you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIKN9vbbUIw&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       HyperLink hlControl = new HyperLink();
       hlControl.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text; 
       hlControl.NavigateUrl = "page.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
       e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(hlControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like exactly what I need, this literally opens me up a whole world of possibilities

Comment: Just got to try out the code, it gives an exception because apparently the new cell was declared, the fix was easy, just needed to add `e.Row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());`
I'll be editing your answer with the right code

Answer (score 1):

Use [HyperlinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:HyperlinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="page.aspx?ID={0}" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">    
  <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="VisibleText" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval(columnname) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>    
  </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>           
</asp:GridView>
```